# Variable failed to be shown after inserting in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
const jQuery = jQuery;
const optNumber = jQuery('.notificationCenter__list li').length;
const html2 = `
<span class="optHeaderMdSm__notification__unread">(jQuery('.notificationCenter__list li').length)</span>
`;
jQuery('.headerLg__notification .link__icon').after(html).remove('.headerLg__notification .link__icon');
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is the problem you have with the code you show? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If your element is showing the text `"jQuery('.notificationCenter__list li').length"` and not the value, use `${optNumber }` in your literal string: `const html2 = \`<span class="optHeaderMdSm__notification__unread">${optNumber}</span>\`;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
const optNumber = jQuery('.notificationCenter__list li').length;
const html2 = `
<span class="optHeaderMdSm__notification__unread">(${optNumber})</span>
`;
jQuery('.headerLg__notification .link__icon').after(html2);

// Remove the link__icon element
jQuery('.headerLg__notification .link__icon').remove();
```

Make sure that you have properly included the jQuery library in your HTML page before using jQuery functions.